# Display data from two tables with relationship

Tags: laravel

How can I join two Laravel tables?

Using the code below, I don't see any errors, but in the web page where should the email be? It shows nothing.

Everything else what is taken from posts table is correct, but the relationship data do not show.

#### ViewPostsController.php

```
    use App\Post;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ViewPostsController extends Controller
    {
        public function posts()
        {
            $posts = Post::latest()->get();
            $email = DB::table('posts')->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->get();
            return view('posts', compact('posts', 'email'));
        }
    }
```

#### posts.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <div class="container">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100">
                    </div>
                    <p> Kategorija: {{ $post->category }}</p>
                    <p> Apraksts: {{ $post->description }}</p>
                    <p> Cena: {{ $post->price }}</p>
                    <p>e-pasts:{{ $post->email }}</p></div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endsection
```

#### Posts database structure

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
                $table->string('category');
                $table->string('description');
                $table->decimal('price',5,2);
                $table->string('image');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->index('user_id');
            });
```

users database structure

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s assume that your **$posts = Post::latest()** is already returning the query needed to display the posts you need. You just have to join the users table and tell the query which fields to select.

Example:

```php
$query = Post::latest();
$query->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(['posts.*', 'users.email']);
$posts = $query->get();
```

This way your **$posts** variable should contain the array of objects with the needed information.

Answer (score 1):

Better use relationships in Laravel -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

It is very simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eloquent relationship.
In your Post model add this.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->latest()->get();
```

Then in your view files you can access it using

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <div class="container">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100">
                    </div>
                    <p> Kategorija: {{ $post->category }}</p>
                    <p> Apraksts: {{ $post->description }}</p>
                    <p> Cena: {{ $post->price }}</p>
                    <p>e-pasts:{{ $post->user->email }}</p></div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endsection
```

You can read more about relationships here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: This would generate the n+1 problem. You need to add to the PostsController `Post::latest()->with('user')->get()`